# The benefits of upgrading form swagger 1.5 to 2 or 3

Tags: swagger, java-annotations

I am working on a project that is using java annotations for swagger 1.5. We are looking at improving the information in our documentation i.e. is it correct and can we make it better. In researching this I see swagger 2 and 3 are available now. In searching around I see all kinds of information on how to convert tools and ... but I am not seeing information on why we should.
So the question is what are the benefits of swagger 2 and 3 that are not available in 1.5?